# How to Prevent Main Thread from Freezing during Excel Export with 100,000 Records in AG Grid

Tags: ag-grid

I'm currently using the Excel export feature in AG Grid. However, I'm facing an issue where the main thread freezes when exporting Excel files with around 100,000 records. This significantly affects the user experience, as the UI becomes unresponsive during the export process.

I’m looking for suggestions to prevent the UI from freezing during the export process.
Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.